# Heroku postgres pgpool-II support for read only query load balancing

Tags: postgresql, heroku, load-balancing, pgpool

TL:DR Does Heroku support pgpool-II for master-slave read only load balancing? Other solutions?

We are planning to go live with our application on heroku within the next couple of months. The biggest potential scaling hurdle at the moment for us is getting past the database connection limits. We've already employed pgbouncer. (https://github.com/gregburek/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer) Now we are looking at master-slave read only query load balancing. We would prefer to use something like pgpool instead of rolling our own in-app balancer. (playframework)

Vertical scaling of the database doesn't make much sense for us because the size of data will remain relatively small. Plus the price or higher heroku db tiers increases exponentially. (we would prefer linear scale)

Have you had success with read only query load balancing on heroku? What was your approach?

Comment: I have no experience with Heroku. But some comments related to pgpool. If you are considering pgpool-II, why not use it for pooling also? Do go through this discussion if you are employing pgpool-II, just giving a heads-up. I have found it to be a very good tool (other than  this terminate back-end ) http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/How-to-know-killed-by-pg-terminate-backend-td2017927.html

Comment: @Jayadevan I added pgbouncer first because it was recommended by heroku and had simple setup instructions. I wouldn't mind doing the pooling through pgpool if I could figure out how to set it up with heroku. So far my google foo has failed me.